# How do I copy the URL under the cursor?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

In Vim, I can use `gx` in normal mode to open the URL under the cursor. Instead of opening the URL, how can I copy the URL?

I am looking for something faster than entering into visual mode, selecting the URL, and yanking the selected URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the same mechanism that can capture file paths, [`<cfile>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#:%3Ccfile%3E):

```
<cfile>    is replaced with the path name under the cursor (like what |gf| uses)
```

This special keyword can be resolved to its associated value on the command line using the function [`expand()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expand()). For example, to put the URL in a register:

```
:let @0 = expand('<cfile>')
```

If you want to put the URL in the clipboard use [`"*`](https://vimhelp.org/gui.txt.html#clipboard) or [`"+`](https://vimhelp.org/gui_x11.txt.html#quoteplus) register (depending on your system and its configuration).

Add it to a mapping...

```
:nnoremap <leader>u :let @* = expand('<cfile>')<CR>
```

...and with a couple key presses you can now paste the URL wherever you need it.

---

**Update:** A couple Q&As excerpted from the comments that may be useful to others...

**Q:** *When I press `p` in normal mode to paste the URL, why is nothing pasted?*

**A:** The type of environment (OS, window manager, GUI vs terminal) you're in usually dictates which register is tied to the system clipboard. If paste/put is working for you otherwise look at the register being used there and use the same in the mapping. If you're using *nix the "quote-plus" register (`@+`) may be what you need. (*ed- It was.*) For more details on clipboard use `:h 'clipboard'` is a good place in Vim help to start.

**Q:** *How can I prevent the mapped command from appearing in the status bar? `:nnoremap <leader>u :silent let@* ...` doesn't work.*

**A:** Instead of using `:silent` add `<silent>` after `nnoremap`.

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>u :let @* = expand('<cfile>')<CR>
```

`<silent>` is simply used to prevent a mapped command from being displayed when the mapped keys are entered. If the mapped command also has output that you don't want to see you'll need `:silent` *in addition* to `<silent>`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this silent? I tried `nnoremap <leader>u :silent let @* = expand('<cfile>')<CR>` in my vimrc, but it doesn't seem to make the keybinding silent.

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I press `p` in normal mode to paste the URL, nothing is pasted.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. It works now. I was actually looking for one solution for pasting into Vim and another for pasting outside it. I should have mentioned that in my question. Anyway, `nnoremap <silent> <leader>u :let @+ = expand('<cfile>')<CR>` works perfectly for pasting outside Vim. For pasting inside Vim, I replaced the `@+` with `@"`. I am using terminal Vim on Ubuntu.